# problem of modifying a column with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe for which I want to create a new column called result which should take the value "refuse" if the value of the column "mean" is less than 10 otherwise the refuse column should take the value "Admitted".

[[image: this is the image of my dataframe I want to create a "result" column that takes the value admitted and refuse 1]

Comment: Don't put image. Update as text format. and also add expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
import numpy as np
data['new_col'] = np.where(data['mean'] < 10, 'refuse', 'Admitted')
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir Dishin H Goyani  you really helped me I searched all night and in less than 3 minutes you solved the problem for me.

Comment: Happy to help!!

Answer (score 0):

```
data.loc[(data['mean'] < 10), 'result'] = 'Refuse'
data.loc[(data['mean'] >= 10), 'result'] = 'Admitted'
```